# Is this probability positive?

Tags: probability, inequality

Let $X$ be a random variable such that $\mathbb{P}(X=0)<1$ and $\mathbb{E}X=-\varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon>0$.

Can you show that $\mathbb{P}(X>0)>0$ ?

It is natural to expect that the inequality may hold only for sufficiently small and positive $\varepsilon$.

Update. Let's add that $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\mathbb{E}X^2>0.$$

Comment: What if $X=-\varepsilon$ with probability $1$?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not true : with a random variable such as $P(X=0)=1-\varepsilon< 1$ and $P(X=-1)=\varepsilon$, you will have $P(X>0)=0$ and $\mathbb{E}X=-\varepsilon$.

Comment: Ok, inequality fails for such distribution. But there are distributions for which it holds. Are there known any general conditions that the inequality could be true?